# Number of arrangements in a line where there are 2 or more groups that have 2 or more members that cannot be adjacent to each other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Consider the following pattern of characters:**

$$ABFDEFA$$

I am tasked to find the number of arrangements where repeating characters in the pattern's permutation cannot sit next to each other.

**My Solution:**

I've only tried arranging a line where there are spaces between the repeating characters like so:

$$\_A\_A\_F\_F\_$$

**Edit:** forgot to say the repeating characters are distinguishable.

Then from that, find all the possible permutations of the repeating characters multiplied by $^5P_3$ since we can only choose 3 spaces from 5 available ones:

$$\frac{4!5!}{(5-3)!}$$

But this only gets me **1440** which is really too far away from the given answer which is **2640**. What's the best solution for my problem here?

Comment: I assume you mean combinations, not permutations, e.g., the two $A$s are indistinguishable, right? And the string you give is seven long, yet your string with the _s is nine long?

Comment: Using Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: @Lovsovs they're different from each other.

Comment: What about the string lengths, or do you want the solution for an arbitrarily long string?

Comment: There are only $$\frac{7!}{2!2!} = 1260$$ distinguishable arrangements of the letters $AABDEFF$, so the given answer cannot be correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Apparently the repeating letters are distinguishable.

Comment: Hint:  Easier to work backward.  Exclude those that contain $A_1A_2$ or $A_2A_1$ as blocks, same with the $F_i$.  Add back those that contain both sorts of blocks.

Comment: Note:  I think it's worth editing the question.  As stated, every reader will assume the $A's$ and the $F's$ are indistinguishable.  I'd say it's clearer if you start from the word $A_1BF_1DEF_2A_2$.

Comment: @Lovsovs the string lengths should be the same(7 from the given example). The _'s or slot spaces are 5 long because the left-over/non-repeating characters can start from the First slot space, or the Second, or Third, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is stipulated that the repeated letters are distinguishable, we wish to find the number of permutations of $A\mathcal{A}BDEF\mathcal{F}$ in which $A$ is not adjacent to $\mathcal{A}$ and $F$ is not adjacent to $\mathcal{F}$.

If there were no restrictions, the seven letters could be arranged in $7!$ ways.  From these, we exclude those arrangements in which one or more of the restrictions is violated.

If $A$ and $\mathcal{A}$ are adjacent, we place them in an amber colored box.  We then have six objects to arrange, the box and the other five letters.  They can be arranged in $6!$ ways.  The letters $A$ and $\mathcal{A}$ can be arranged in $2!$ ways within the box.  Hence, there are $6!2!$ arrangements in which $A$ is adjacent to $A$.

By similar argument, there are $6!2!$ arrangements in which $F$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{F}$.

However, if we subtract $2 \cdot 6!2!$ from $7!$, we will have subtracted those in which $A$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{A}$ and $F$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{F}$ twice, once when we subtracted those arrangements in which $A$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{A}$ and once when we subtracted those arrangements in which $F$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{F}$.  Therefore, we need to add the number of arrangements in which $A$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{A}$ and $F$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{F}$.

If we place $A$ and $\mathcal{A}$ in an amber colored box and place $F$ and $\mathcal{F}$ in a fuchsia colored box, we have five objects to arrange.  They can be arranged in $5!$ ways.  The object in each box can be arranged in $2!$ ways.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which $A$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{A}$ and $F$ is adjacent to $\mathcal{F}$ is $5!2!2!$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of valid arrangements is 
$$7! - 2 \cdot 6!2! + 5!2!2! = 2640$$

Comment: Can you explain how taking away the two same letters from the 7 ones can give us 6! ? Pretty new to discrete mathematics as you can see..

Comment: If we place $A$ and $\mathcal{A}$ in an amber colored box, we have six objects to arrange, the box and the other five letters.  They can be arranged in $6!$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

First let us count the number of arrangements in which $A_1A_2$ and $F_1F_2$ are together. This is $4 \times 120 = 480$ ways - since considering these as blocks, we need to arrange 5 positions and within their blocks there are 2 ways each of them to be together. Next count ways in which $A_1A_2$ are together but $F_1, F_2$ are not. This is arrange $(A_1A_2), B, D, E$ in $4! \times 2$ ways and in the 5 gaps between these, choose 2 to arrange $F_1, F_2$.Thus there are $4! \times 2 \times 5 \times 4 = 960$. Similarly there are 960 ways in which $F_1, F_2$ are together while $A_1, A_2$ are not. Thus the number of ways is 
\begin{align*}
 7! - 960 - 960 - 480 = 2640
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{Another\;\; way}$

We can apply the "gap method" followed by the "subtraction method".

Initially, we take letters of the same kind to be indistinguishable, as is customary.

Firstly, we shall keep the $F's$ separate by placing them in the **gaps** of $-A-A-B-D-E-$ and permute the other letters, thus $\binom62\cdot\frac{5!}{2!} = 900$ ways.

We shall now **subtract** arrangements with the $A's$ together treating them as a super $A$,
$ -\mathscr A - B-D-E-  \;,$  thus $\binom52\cdot4! = 240$

The ans with repeated letters indistinguishable is thus $900 -240 = 660$

but since you say they are distinguishable, multiply by $2!2!$ to get $\boxed{2640}$